# JavaFX 2 Does setting cache ( setCache(true) ) on parent Node affect children Nodes?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

If I set caching `setCache(true)` on parent `Node`, will the children nodes also be cached?

Lets say I have a `StackPane` with a gradient and another `Pane` also with gradient but rotating on it. What will happen when:

1. I set caching only on parent
2. I set caching only on child
3. I set caching on both.
4. I won't set caching.

Comment: isCache of the children of the node is still false, if that is what you mean.

Comment: @Sebastian I made an edit, please check if you can.